# Stop Scrapy spider when date from page is older that yesterday

Tags: scrapy

This code is part of my Scrapy spider:

```
# scraping data from page has been done before this line

publish_date_datetime_object = (datetime.strptime(publish_date, '%d.%m.%Y.')).date()

yesterday = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).date()

if publish_date_datetime_object > yesterday:
    continue

if publish_date_datetime_object < yesterday:
    raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider('---STOP---DATE IS OLDER THAN YESTERDAY')

# after this is ItemLoader and yield
```

This is working fine.

**My question is Scrapy spider best place to have this code/logic?**

I do not know how to put implement it in another place.
Maybe it can be implemented in a pipeline, but AFAIK the pipeline is evaluated after the scraping has been done, so that means that I need to scrape all adds, even thous that I do not need.
A scale is 5 adds from yesterday versus 500 adds on the whole page.
I do not see any benefit in moving code to pipeline it that means processing(downloading and scraping) 500 adds if I only need 5 from it.

Comment: Didn't you already "download and process" the data when scraping it? 

From a maintainer's perspective it might be better to separate concerns. The pipeline is the place where you drop unwanted items and the spider just does the gatherer's task.

Comment: OK, I see/understand your question. Question is correct one. There are multiple pages(one after the another, like pagination), each page has 25 adds on it (if I have 500 adds, then I have 20 pages, and I need to download only first N pages, nothing after).

Comment: That's right, should have known from the code, sorry. Then it makes total sense to me leaving it inside the spider, it really saves resources in a practical way.

Comment: @RubénCabrera if you want, write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I'm trying to improve it a little bit so it doesn't feel like cheating and it's useful for someone else. Can you think of any way of making this a bit more general?

Comment: @RubénCabrera I have no idea :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the right place if you need your spider to stop crawling after something indicates there's no more useful data to collect.

It is also the right way to do it, rising a CloseSpider exception with a verbose closing reason message.

A pipeline would be more suitable only if there were items to be collected after the threshold detected, but if they are ALL disposable this would be a waste of resources.